# Customer view for Team Foundation Service

Tags: reporting-services, azure-devops

My team recently migrated from onsite to the cloud Team Foundation Service 2012.

We had also maintained a separate SharePoint portal with extranet capabilities to list projects/tasks etc. for external customers

Seeing that we're now online, I was wondering if there is a means to restrict a view to PBIs/Certain properties of tasks [Time Elapsed, Time Remaining] for certain accounts.

Alternatively, I recall seeing SSRS capabilities in the on site version. Is there a means to configure reports (scheduled/manual) using the Team Foundation Service?

Edit:
Alternatively, are there any methods (web services/command line/???) to produce this info in a format which could be parsed to facilitate the generation of some report automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Team Foundation Service, there is not currently a way to integrate SQL Reporting Services.  However, the OData feeds are available with the Team Foundation Service that allows you to get real-time data programmatically.  Here's some more information about the OData feeds:  https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/

You can also use the traditional Team Foundation Server SDK to interact with the Team Foundation Service as well.

Comment: Thanks Ed. This looks like my best bet. I can almost feel the power already.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing I have seen in TFS that will allow either of these I'm afraid.

The current security model, doesn't accommodate that. Only restrictions, by Area / Iteration and Team Project can be applied, the same as the on-premise version.

As for SSRS, I seem to recall (I can't cite a source) people hinting that it's on the backlog, but it's not available at on the Service the moment.